# Get the id of the checked input checkboxes and add to a list

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, checkbox, updatepanel

I'll start off saying, i know hardly anything about java script and i have a feeling this requires it. What i would like to do is find out which checkboxes are checked, add those to a list and pass that to the code behind page.

This is how i create the checkboxes from the results i get.

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
     <%foreach (var qv in rs)
     {
         var checkid = "chk" + qv.id;
         var tdid = "td" + qv.id;
         var text = qv.text.ToString();                                          
      %>
      <tr >
           <td width="100%">
           <input type="checkbox" id="<%=qv.id%>" value="@qv.id" />
           </td>
           <td width="100%">
           <%=qv.text%>
           </td>
      </tr>
      <%                                      
      } %>
</table>
```

Can anyone help me?

So I found exactly what I'm looking for but when I use the code, nothing works, even when I copy paste it exactly it doesnt work, am I missing something silly?

Here is the link to the working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dvCmR/
and here is my code, exactly the same but not working.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#clickme").click(function (e) {
        var selected = $("#checkboxes input:checked").map(function (i, el) { return el.name; }).get();
        alert("selected = [" + selected + "]\nas string = \"" + selected.join(";") + "\"");
    });
</script>
<div id="checkboxes">
    <input id="chkbx_0" type="checkbox" name="c_n_0" checked="checked" />Option 1
    <input id="chkbx_1" type="checkbox" name="c_n_1" />Option 2
    <input id="chkbx_2" type="checkbox" name="c_n_2" />Option 3
    <input id="chkbx_3" type="checkbox" name="c_n_3" checked="checked" />Option 4
</div>
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="click me, now!" />
```

Comment: You can set a "selected" class to your checkboxes when they are selected and using JQueryUI select them by class as $(".selected")

Comment: `function getCheckedCheckBoxes(){
  var ids = [];
  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
   ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
  });
  $('#hdf_selectedIds').val(JSON.stringify(ids));
 }`

Comment: Or you can set `$('#hdf_selectedIds').val(ids.join(','))` and finally at server side `List<string> selectedIds = hdf_selectedIds.Value.Split(',');`

Comment: @gjijo Thank you for the detail but like I said, i dont know much of javascript so i dont know how exactly to implement your solution, i have updated the question because i found a solution but im not sure what im missing, could you please take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$checkedBoxeIds;`

`$('table').each(function (i, row) {`

`var $row = $(row),`

`$checkedBoxe = $row.find('input:checked')[0];`

`$checkedBoxeIds += $checkedBoxeIds +";"`

`});`

`$.ajax({`

`type: "POST", url: myUrl,data: { checkedIs : $checkedBoxeIds},`

`success: function(data) {`

`alert('it worked');`

`}});`

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, I found a solution to exactly what i want to achieve. I edited the question, could you take a look again please, if its not bothering you

Comment: If you want to get selected checkboxes values, watch this http://jsfiddle.net/dvCmR/673/

Comment: Then you can pass your selected values to server width ajax call

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! everything works smooth now with alil tinkering!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
```

if you need harder selector you can use something like this

`$('td input[type=checkbox]:checked')`